# How to rename file before ->download() with Laravel Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

Can't find in docs of Laravel Excel how to give a new name for loaded file before give it for download. I've tried ->setTitle but it doesn't work.

```
Excel::load(public_path().'/bills/bill.template.xlsx', function($doc) {

            $doc->setTitle = 'test';
            $sheet = $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            $sheet->setCellValue('G21', '{buyer}');
            $sheet->setCellValue('AB24', '{sum}');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B30', '{sum_propis}');


        })->download('xlsx');
```

It gives me "bill.template.xlsx" when I'm waiting for "test.xlsx"

Comment: I have no idea about this particular library, but file names of downloads are usually controlled by the HTTP headers sent in the response - perhaps you can see if the library does that, or add a header yourself in the response for that purpose.

Comment: `setTitle()` sets the "Title" for the worksheet within the workbook

Comment: @MarkBaker I know, that was just a try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used this library before, but looking at the code it looks like you can [set the filename attribute](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/145beff98389ca6ac0b6e037a6a5c5ca867c9f90/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php#L137-L142) which [will then get used in the headers to set the name of the file downloaded](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/145beff98389ca6ac0b6e037a6a5c5ca867c9f90/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php#L317-L342).

Probably something like:

```
Excel::load(public_path().'/bills/bill.template.xlsx', function($doc) 
{...})
    ->setFilename('whatever')
    ->download('xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Excel::download($query, 'TimeSheetExport.xlsx');
$data->setContentDisposition('attachment','TimeSheetExport')->getFile()->move(public_path('xlsx/'), $data->getFile().'xlsx');
```

`$query` is our collection.

'TimeSheetExport.xlsx'  ->  Will not be our file name

in `move()` you can give your file name in second parameter, and first parameter will be the location for that file